# magento 2 get product collection with custom filter on product listing page

Tags: magento2, product, collection

I want to apply my custom attribute filter in category product collection?

**Can any one inform me for that ,i need to override which file ?**

Comment: What you mean by Custom filter?

Comment: @ Amit Bera: I have created one product attribute , and I want to load product collection based on that attribute option value is not null on product listing page .